# Is there a pipefail equivalent for dash?

Tags: shell, scripting, exit-status, dash

I have a perl script that runs a `system()` call to execute shell commands and I would like to run more than one command and pipe data between them. Something like (in perl):

```perl
system("command1 | command2");
```

Perl's `system()` uses `/bin/sh` and since these are running on an Ubuntu Server system, `/bin/sh` is `dash`. Like many other shells, the exit value of a pipeline in dash is the exit value of the right-most command. This means that something like this will return `0` (success):

```perl
system("false | true")
```

If I were on a system whose `/bin/sh` were `bash`, I could fix it easily by adding the `pipefail` option:

```perl
system("set -o pipefail; false | true");
```

Indeed, this works as expected on my local Arch system whose `/bin/sh` points to `bash`:

```bash
$ perl -le '$status = system("false | true"); print $status>>8'
0
$ perl -le '$status = system("set -o pipefail; false | true"); print $status>>8'
1
```

<sub>(Yes, I know this looks weird, but if you don't know Perl, just take my word for it: we need to shift by 8 to get the actual exit status)</sub>

However, since the machine it is supposed to run on has `dash`, the same thing fails:

```bash
$ perl -le '$status = system("set -o pipefail; false | true"); print $status>>8'
sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
2
```

Using `set -e` is also not a solution:

```bash
$ perl -le '$status = system("set -e; false | true"); print $status>>8'
0
```

I can think of some Perl workarounds, such as not piping or using the `IPC::System::Simple` module, but I was hoping there might be a simpler way to do this directly in dash.

So, is there some trick, hack or option that lets me tell `dash` that the exit status of a set of piped commands should only be `0` (success) if *all* commands worked and should be non-0 if any of them failed the way that `set -o pipefail` works in `bash`?

Comment: Not a solution, but an idea: You could run a bash from the dash that's started by perl. Something like ```system("bash -c 'set -o pipefail; false | true; echo $?'")```.

Comment: What programs do you need to run as a pipe using `system`? Wouldn't it be possible to implement parts of the pipeline (or even everything) in Perl?

Comment: @anick yeah, I could do that. It's ugly, but it should work. I might resort to it if I can't find anything simpler, thanks!

Comment: @Bodo yes, it would be, but I'm largely wondering if there's some way of doing it in dash itself. I can think of various workarounds, but the thrust of this question is about whether there's some dash trick I don't know about.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17757039/19456361

Comment: Isn't the point of dash to _not have tricks_?

Comment: `status >> 8` is normal. Shells are weird for mangling the 16-bit exit status word into a different form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about doing it in Dash, but you can bypass `/bin/sh` completely.

Perl's `system()` tries to guess what the programmer wants, and uses `sh -c` only if there's just one argument, and that argument contains shell metacharacters. Otherwise it runs the given command directly, and you can specify the exact arguments (including the command name that goes in `argv[0]` or `$0` in the shell, that's passed through an "indirect object").

[The docs say](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#system-LIST):

> Note that argument processing varies depending on the number of arguments. If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the rest of the list.
>
> If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is `/bin/sh -c` on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).

These two would make the same `execve()` call:

```
system{"/bin/sh"} ("sh", "-c", 'false |true; echo $?')
system('false |true; echo $?')
```

Namely, this one, as shown by `strace`:

```
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "false |true; echo $?"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
```

<sub>(`system("sh", "-c", '...')` would be similar but would look in `$PATH` for `sh`, and
`system("/bin/sh", "-c", '...')` would differ ever so slightly in that it'd pass `/bin/sh` in `argv[0]` for the launched shell instead of just `sh`. No big differences.)</sub>

Hence, we can just run this in Perl:

```
system("bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c", 'false |true; echo $?');
# or a bit shorter
system(qw/bash -o pipefail -c/, 'false |true; echo $?');
```

and we avoid the round-trip through `sh`, *and* the associated double-quoting for the Bash command line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really really ugly yet functional solution for you:

```bash
system(q{
  exec 3>&1; \
  status1="$(((false 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- 4>&-; echo $? >&4) \
    | true 1>&2 3>&- 4>&-) 4>&1)"; \
  status2=$? \
  [ $status2 != 0 ] && exit $status2; \
  exit $status1
});
```

You can remove those backslashes, line breaks, and indentation if you want it all on one line. This was adapted from the [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) essay, § 1d "More Elaborate Combinations" [of things Posix shell can do and Csh cannot].

This opens file descriptor 3 to temporarily store stdout, then runs the first command and re-plumbs where its output goes: FD4 and FD3 are closed, FD1 (standard output) goes into FD3, and FD2 (standard error) goes to FD1. Then it puts the exit code into FD4 before running the second command. The second command gets its FD4 and FD3 closed, then puts its standard output into FD2 (I believe its stderr actually prints and this may include stdout, but I may not be reading the magic correctly). With the output printed, it's safe to return FD4 to stdout and then that is what's stored in `$status1`. Assigning `$status2` is more straightforward since the second command's status populates `$?`. Now we just have to implement `pipefail`. If `$status2` is not a clean exit of 0, exit with it. Otherwise, exit with whatever `$status1` stored.

Add new file descriptors (5, 6, etc) and `$status` variables for more pipes.

That gives you Posix compliance and portability, but you're far better off doing this more natively in perl or else using [anick's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/710772/87770#comment1345794_710772) and invoking bash (assuming that's an option), which certainly seems elegant in comparison:

```perl
system("bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c", 'false |true; echo $?')
```

(Arguments broken out for safer implementation within perl, see [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711395/87770) for details regarding that invocation.)